# How can I apply styles globally to an Angular2 application?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-template

To give the exact scenario I'm facing, I am trying to use Webpack to bundle Zurb's Foundation package into my application. Looking at the bundled JS, the Foundation SCSS *is* getting imported, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my application's render.

I tried a `require('../../node_modules/foundation.scss/foundation.scss)` in the root component's style attribute and that does seem to style that component's HTML, but not the HTML of any child components.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I may be misunderstanding but it sounds like you have found a way to include the main foundation css into the root component but this css is then not applied to any other components am I right?

If this is the case then I think you need to set the root component to use:
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

Inside your root component you need to import this:

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
```

and then do this:

```
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'global-css',
    templateUrl: 'global-css.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['global-css.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

ViewEncapsulation.None basically says don't scope the css to this component only.

If for some reason doing this in the root component is not allowed, try creating a 'global-css' component that has ViewEncapsulation.None and then just import this component into your root app component

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extract text plugin for webpack. "It moves every require("style.css") in entry chunks into a separate css output file. So your styles are no longer inlined into the javascript, but separate in a css bundle file (styles.css). If your total stylesheet volume is big, it will be faster because the stylesheet bundle is loaded in parallel to the javascript bundle."

```
https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

Only do this for the css you wont be modifying, as hot reload wont be available. I presume you wont be making modification to foundation.css, so only create a separate bundled css for that

Answer (score -1):

If you include css files in the index.html file in your root folder they should be applied to your entire application.

Otherwise you can use the style property within your components meta data to include specific css files to specific components.

Update due to clarification in comments:

Comment: Can you expand on that to explain how this would work with Webpack? I'm not sure how to inject Webpacked CSS without it being in a JS file.

Comment: Updated answer.  Is the question how to compile scss to css?  If so, there are plenty of links showing how to do that.

Comment: No. Webpack is correctly compiling my SCSS to CSS and injecting that CSS into my bundle.js file. What I'm not sure how to do is then apply (some of) that CSS to the entire document, as opposed to a lone component via that component's styles attribute. Since there is no independent CSS file to reference as per your example, a simple link tag will not suffice (I wish ...).

Comment: is bundle.js included within your index.html page? Without seeing how you are using webpack it would be difficult to answer your question.  But the above principal applies, which is that css included in index.html will be global, but a component will only have access to css included within that components style attribute.